# Jquery validation occurs only for the first dynamic control not for other dynamic controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have used jquery validation plugin for validation purpose. I am creating dynamic controls and adding rules to that controls but while clicking the submit button only first field is validated other fields are not validated.If the first field value is satisfied the form is submitted but other fields are not considered.
How to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $("#dynamicControlForm").validate();
        $("#AddControls").click(function () {
            count++;
            var elements = "<input type='text' id='txt" + count + "'class='required'/><br/></br>";
            $(elements).appendTo("#dynamicControlForm");
            $(".required").rules("add" + count, "required");
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="DynamicControlsContainer">
    <input type="button" name="CreateControl" value="AddControl" id="AddControls" />
    <form action="/" method="post" id="dynamicControlForm">
    <input type="submit" name="DynamicControl" id="btnDynamicSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**Image:**

[image]

**Link**

Link - http://jsfiddle.net/qwuPk/1/

**Link2**

http://jsfiddle.net/LtAy5     I have added the code for drop down, radio and checkbox

Comment: Validation is not happening for checkbox,radiobutton and dropdown

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug in your add rule method

```
$("#AddControls").click(function () {
    count++;
    var elements = "<input type='text' id='txt" + count + "' name='txt" + count + "' class='rec'/><br/></br>";
    var $elem = $(elements).appendTo("#dynamicControlForm");
    $elem.rules("add", {
        required: true
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pj94u/)

Comment: I tried your code but i don't see any difference. It's not working.

Comment: Validation occurs only for the first control

Comment: @my1 sorry... minor bug fixed

Comment: I tried ur code but the thing is if i click submit button the error message is displayed for first textbox but for others nothing is displayed. I type something in the first textbox the error is cleared and if i press the submit button the form is submitted.  I have attached the js fiddle link for your reference.

Comment: I tried ur code it's working only for textbox but not for radiobutton, checkbox and dropdown. I have posted the code in JsFiddle. Please find the link http://jsfiddle.net/LtAy5/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go for an approach of validating form after adding your dynamic control on your page on button click event. In this scenario, you need to validate your form then apply following code block,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $("#AddControls").click(function () {
            count++;
            var elements = "<input type='text' id='txt" + count + "'class='required'/><br/></br>";
            $("#dynamicControldiv").append(elements);
            $(".required").rules("add" + count, "required");
        });

          $("#btnDynamicSubmit").on("click", function () {
        var textlength = $("input[type='text']").attr("class", "required");
        for (var i = 1; i <= textlength.length; i++) {
            var id = $("#txt" + i).attr('id');
            var value = $("#txt" + i).attr('value');
            if (value == "") {
                $("#txt" + i).attr("required", "required");
            }
        }
        var validation = $("#dynamicControlForm"); //Your form id.
        if (!validation.valid()) {
            $("input[type='text']").attr("required", "required");
            return false;
        }

    });
    });
</script>
```

**View**

```
<div id="DynamicControlsContainer">
    <input type="button" name="CreateControl" value="AddControl" id="AddControls" />
    <form action="/" method="post" id="dynamicControlForm">
    <div id="dynamicControldiv">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="DynamicControl" id="btnDynamicSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/qwuPk/2/

Comment: sorry i don't understand validation message is not show right?

Comment: yes the validation messages are not displaying for all the controls only for the first control it's getting displayed. If first text box is valid the form is submitted . It doesn't bothers about other controls. I tried your approach previously but it fails

Comment: I just update my code. Try this code in your project if it's not working on demo. because now it's perfectly working on my project.